# How does jQuery selection work behind the scene?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Which one of the following selectors has better performance, if not the same

1. `$('#location_form input#id_name')`
2. `$('#id_name')`

I often have questions like the above pop up in my mind. I can't really answer them because I lack the knowledge on how selection work behind the scene.

My asks:

1. answer/opinions to the question above
2. references that explain how jQuery selection work behind the scene
3. do all javascript frameworks work in the same way as jQuery when it comes to selection?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It may seem obvious, but speed aside, the above expressions are not actually the same. You may have a case where you want to select an element by id, but only if it happens to be inside another specific element and is an input element. For example, you may be moving that element around the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your selectors, the latter is faster, as jQuery determines you only want to select by ID and returns `document.getElementByID`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L145-165

Here is the full source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L78-188

Comment: KorvinSzanto - Thanks for your answer. What you said, does it apply to all cases, even for large documents? My intuition tells me that, for large documents, the divide-and-conquer approach (ie. #1) might be faster, as indicated by @GreyBeardedGeek. I want to hear your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the browsers application of `document.getElementById`.  It's my understanding that the page searches for the element with that ID and stops once it finds it, it doesn't make sense that it would be faster to search for the parent then iterate through each child looking for the specific ID. In other words, the latter has to search for one id, while the former has to search for two, which is much less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

As usual, "it depends".
For a trivially small document, there's not much difference.

For a larger document, #1 can have much better performance, because it limits the search to descendants of the element with the id of 'location_form', while #2 would search the entire document.

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and more specifically, http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: GreyBeardedGeek- What you said contradicts with @KorvinSzanto's answer, so I am still unsure. Would you be able to direct me to any references that could back up your answer? The provided links only show the jQuery selectors but they don't explain how things work behind the scene.

Comment: Actually, in this specific case, @KorvinSzanto is correct, because your most specific selector is an id, searching by id alone is probably fastest, as most browsers don't actually search the DOM directly for ids, but typically have some quick lookup method, such as a hashmap.

However, if you are searching for something by class, or something else where an actual DOM traversal is required, specifying a scope by id is faster, since it cuts down on how much of the DOM needs to be searched.

Comment: Also, if you have a performance-critical application:

1. cache the results of your selectors so that you don't have to re-run them when you need them multiple times.

2. test - actually measure the performance, and see if it's really a problem before you change anything. Don't do premature optimization.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks GreyBeardedGeek. You are awesome!